# re-sort angularjs ngRepeat with subsequent data results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a case where I need to repeat over results from various ajax sources. I can't wait for all sources to load before rendering, I must render the results as they come in. But I want the results to be in a particular order (alphabetical as it so happens). ngRepeat sorts them accordingly if all results are present at the same time, but not if they are loaded asynchronously.

How can I re-sort the repeat after all the results are loaded?

I've created a [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kfeHghW8yfC6g81mE50E) to simulate the async ajax and the out of order results I get.

Here is an overly simplified, somewhat contrived sample of what I'm doing (for illustration purposes only, because SO requires code).

```
// ngRepeat over $scope.prices in correct order
// all ajax loaded then $scope.prices assigned
var priority = ['1 Day', '3 Day', 'Ground'];
var prices = {};
for(var i = 0; i < priority.length; ++i) {
    $http.get('some/endpoint/' + priority[i])
    .then(function(response) {
        prices[priority[i]] = response.data;
    });
}
$scope.prices = {
    '1 Day': prices['1 Day'],
    '3 Day': prices['3 Day'],
    'Ground': prices['Ground']
};

// ngRepeat over $scope.prices in order of successful load
// $scope.prices keys assigned as results are available
var priority = ['1 Day', '3 Day', 'Ground'];
for(var i = 0; i < priority.length; ++i) {
    $http.get('some/endpoint/' + priority[i])
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.prices[priority[i]] = response.data;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your main.html, you can make use of the orderBy function provided by angular

```
    <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(priority, rates) in prices">
    <h2>{{priority}}</h2>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="prices in rates | orderBy:'price'">{{prices.price}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

this will take the array as it comes in and sorts the output

Comment: It's not the rates ordering I'm concerned with, it's the actual order of the priorities themselves, i.e. I want to the order to be 1 Day, 3 Day, Ground, regardless of when those results arrive.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use order and apply a value for each price object's (1 day, 2 day, ground), etc.. ?

As far as the render, could you have the ng-repeat refresh on-click when you update the list, and possibly apply a fade in / out?